# large data retrieve waterfall strategy is a huge bottleneck, how to stream?

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net

**Question Summary: How to get the same query performance of SSMS for large results sets on
.NET??**

I'm using the most recommended strategy to retrieve a relatively large QueryResult from a set of tables. The query itself is used for detailed financial analysis and cannot be further reduced in size. The result is ~ 30K rows of ~40 fields, including all kind of datatypes, but the largest field is still nvarchar(50)

After investigating the back-to-back performance results from SSMS compared to Standard ADO.NET Sqlcommand, **performance for full data retrieval is at least 3x faster on SSMS than on .NET, running from a remote server onto the same client computer.
Typically, SSMS is 10s while the .NET is > 40s.**

What I came to the conclusion is:
***SSMS starts retrieving data as soon as Rows are prepared by the SQL Server.***

***With .NET -->*** first the SQL server prepares the entire result in Memory, this creates a lot of memory pressure on the Server, and which I can see on the Performance monitor, 70% of the  time is spent allocating this memory.

Once the result set is complete, then the SQL server sends the entire result set to .NET in a single operation, .NET buffers this in memory.

From here, control is gave back to the .NET program, which then retrieves from this buffer row by row... The code is highly optimized at this point.

.NET Documentation about asynchronous behavior is the same (BeginExecuteReader call)

```
using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, finalConnection) { AcceptChangesDuringFill = false, FillLoadOption = LoadOption.Upsert, MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.Add }) // UpdateBatchSize improves nothing
{
    //  ALL SQL WORK ALWAYS DONE HERE, default CommandBehaviour does not improve anything  
    using (var reader = adapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess)) 
    {
       // BY Now all data is already in .NET internal buffers
       int colsint = reader.FieldCount;

       var arraylist = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Array>();

       object[] rowInt;  
       while (reader.Read())
       {
          reader.GetValues(rowInt);
          arraylist.Add(rowInt);
       }
       return arrayList;
    }
}
```

Comment: " performance for full data retrieval is at least 3x faster on SSMS than on .NET, running from a remote server onto the same client computer. Typically, SSMS is 10s while the .NET is > 40s."   -  https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Comment: "How to get the same query performance of SSMS for large results sets on .NET??" - strictly speaking that question doesn't make sense outside of parameter sensitive plans.

Comment: *Maybe* the queries aren't as "identical" as you think either. A "classic" is passing an `nvarchar` parameter from the application in a `WHERE` clause against a `varchar` column, making the query non-SARGable. There are many reasons why 2 apparently similar queries can perform differently, but you haven't even given us the query here.

Comment: @larnu : good point

Comment: SSMS uses the same .NET SqlClient libraries as other .NET framework apps. Neither the database engine nor the client libraries prepare the entire result set in memory; results are streamed back to the client as they become available. Of course, you will not see partial results unless you render them before the query completes.

Comment: Most likely the execution plan you are getting in the app has a blocking operator such as a sort or hash, whereas the execution plan in SSMS does not have this. See the link posted by @MitchWheat. Please share the execution plans via https://pastetheplan.com, we cannot diagnose the issue without this.

Comment: You want to belay type binding in general for performance and specifically having a data adapter is already working against because for the adapter to fill with something in a converted format, we're already doing loads to data which doesn't truly perform like you have noticed